# PHP on Apache 2.2.x how to use?

Tags: windows, apache2, php-5.3

I am using Windows XP SP3. I have installed Apache 2.2.9 followed by PHP 5.3 VC6.
I am able to view any plain html on localhost but i can't do so for php files.
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure Apache to use PHP for .php files:

```
 # load module and add handler
 LoadModule php5_module "c:/php/php5apache2.dll"
 AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php

 # configure the path to php.ini
 PHPIniDir "C:/php"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Install has been completed correctly, is your file actually stored as a PHP file? Check the properties of the file.

Try making a php file containing the following code exactly:

When opening in the browser make sure to include the .php at the end:

http://localhost/test.php